# Will it be possible to upgrade the Windows 8.1 (Pro) Preview to the release version?

Tags: windows-8

I'm contemplating upgrading from Windows 8 to the new Windows 8.1 Preview, but I've been unable to find whether it will be technically possible to upgrade from the preview to the full release. It apparently is with Windows RT, but I've found nothing about Windows 8 Pro.

Comment: I'm sure there are good reasons for the down votes this question has been given, but it would be very helpful to know what they are?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault!  Alas, licensing questions are not on topic here; see http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic and http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue for details.

Comment: Yes. The fact that you are not even bothering to read the release declarations of microsoft. This went through the press months ago. Repeatedly. And weeks ago. And days ago. And yesterday.

Comment: @FalconMomot This is not a licensing but a technical question. Especially as 8.1 is a free upgrade / Service pack to 8.0

Comment: I can't say I agree, but that aside, this also isn't something that would reasonably be done in a professional production environment.

Comment: Yes, I intended it as a technical question. I'm well aware of the contents of 8.1 and the fact that it's free - I just couldn't see any reference to whether the preview would be upgradable to the final release without losing stuff in the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingb to Microsoft it is possible but it will wipe all installed desktop software and likely require reinstalling modern apps.

8.0 RTM -> 8.1 RTM : No loss
8.1 Preview -> 8.1 RTM: supported but loss.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/preview-faq

incidentally explains all things in this regard.

Comment: Thank you. Bizarrely I read that FAQ (I thought), but clearly not carefully enough! However, you answer is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my own answer, from Paul Thurrott:

> those who do install the Preview will lose any installed desktop applications or Metro-style apps when they later upgrade to the final release, which should be completed in August.

http://windowsitpro.com/windows-8/windows-81-preview

So, it appears that upgrading to the final release will be supported *but* it will wipe installed applications.

(I still can't find this information in the Microsoft FAQ at http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/preview-faq, although I'm assured it's there - so hopefully this question may help somebody else.)